# parsing timestamptz to consider a timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

A rails 7 application defines

```
    config.time_zone = 'Vienna' 
    config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

A model has two attributes

```
date, :timestamptz  # date is just short for actual column name
date_tz,   :string
```

a form submits data via a time_zone_select and a datetime_select

```
"time_zone"=>"Paris","date_f(3i)"=>"12", "date_f(2i)"=>"1", "date_f(1i)"=>"1999", "date_f(4i)"=>"00", "date_f(5i)"=>"00"
```

The goal is to save the data in postgresql with the proper offset.

the controller can parse the datetime however the slippery part is setting the `local` value

```
local = ??
datetime = DateTime.civil_from_format(local, params[:date_m(1i)], params[:date_m(2i)], params[:date_m(3i)], params[:date_m(4i)], params[:date_m(5i)], 0)
```

A number of issues are at play:

- Possibly some confusion is to the understanding of 'local'...  is local intended as a string representing the offset? *[documentation states](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-c-civil_from_format) Returns DateTime with local offset* An actual example is not indicated, the first assumption that comes to mind is it expects something like `-0400`
- This does not necessarily account for DST: the user is entering in a time zone, but it has yet to be parsed with the date to get a proper offset.  It could be `-0400` or `0300` in DST...
- `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` has no clue as to the offset (save the first), as all underlying value for all elements has `@utc_offset=nil` ... but maybe this is a consequence of setting a timezone in `application.rb` ?

```
> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all
[#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00000001143339b0
  @name="International Date Line West",
  @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: Etc/GMT+12>,
  @utc_offset=nil>,
[...]
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x000000011597f4d0
  @name="Arizona",
  @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::DataTimezone: America/Phoenix>,
  @utc_offset=nil>,
[...]
```

How does one set the proper offset for postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `utc_or_local` argument should either be the symbol `:local` or `:utc`. You can see this through how the method is implemented:

```
  # Returns DateTime with local offset for given year if format is local else
  # offset is zero.
  #
  #   DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2012
  #   # => Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 +0300
  #   DateTime.civil_from_format :local, 2012, 12, 17
  #   # => Mon, 17 Dec 2012 00:00:00 +0000
  def self.civil_from_format(utc_or_local, year, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0)
    if utc_or_local.to_sym == :local
      offset = ::Time.local(year, month, day).utc_offset.to_r / 86400
    else
      offset = 0
    end
    civil(year, month, day, hour, min, sec, offset)
  end
```

If you want to use a specific user provided timezone what you want is `Time.use_zone`:

```
Time.use_zone(the_user_provided_timezone) do
  DateTime.civil_from_format(:local, params[:date_m(1i)], params[:date_m(2i)], params[:date_m(3i)], params[:date_m(4i)], params[:date_m(5i)], 0)
end
```